# Program hangs while execution

Tags: python

When i try to run the following code,no output is displayed and it keeps on running until i press Ctrl+C.Is there a problem in my while loop?Matrix is a 20x20 zero matrix.

```
 while 1:
        y=random.sample(range(1,20),2)
        g=random.sample(range(1,20),2)
        for h in range(0,1):
                t=y[h]
                u=g[h]
                if(t!=u):
                    Matrix[t][u]=1
                    for i in range(numNode):
                        for j in range(numNode):
                                if(Matrix[i][j]==1):
                                    count=count+1
                else:
                    t=y[h+1]
                    u=g[h+1]
                    Matrix[t][u]=1
                    for i in range(numNode):
                        for j in range(numNode):
                                if(Matrix[i][j]==1):
                                    count=count+1
        if(count==40):
            break
print(count)
```

Comment: which line do you think should produce output? Did you forget a `print` statement?

Comment: And also avoid to have so many nested loops.

Comment: The value of numNode is 20?

Comment: yes the value of numNode is 20(which is the length of matrix)

Comment: `for h in range(0,1)` only gives one value, h=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If on each iteration, another 1 is entered into the Matrix, then each time you run through the `for i in range(numNode):` loops, you add the sum of the Matrixso far on to count. i.e., the first time you run, you insert a 1, and count->count+1; but next time you insert another 1, and if it doesn't happen to be the same index as before, count->count+2.

This it's unlikely that you ever hit count==40 exactly. Either make sure you increment count only by 1 every loop, or change the condition to `if(count>=40)`, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Likely you want the following, using numpy functions:

```
matrix = zeros((40,40))
xx,yy = meshgrid( arange(40), arange(40) )
ind1 = random.choice( arange(40*40), size=40, replace=False)
ind2 = random.choice( arange(40*40), size=40, replace=False)
xx.shape = (40*40,)
yy.shape = (40*40,)
matrix[xx[ind1],yy[ind2]] = 1
```

Comment: I changed the code such whenever i add a 1 to the Matrix,i increased the count to 1.However if i want to add about 300 1s to the matrix,the count is always less that.Basically I am trying to add an exact number of 1s to the matrix.For example if k=300,i want to display the matrix which has 300 1s in it at random rows and columns.